# Accessing sharepoint from Powershell-script from c# application

Tags: c#, sharepoint, c#-4.0, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Hello I'm trying to access a sharepoint list from powershell. The powershell script is executed from a c# application.

If I run the from c# application I get the following exception:

> Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The Web application
>   at `http://pc/websites/Test4/` could not be found. Verify that you have
>   typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing
>   content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL
>   mapping to the intended application."

**My Code:**

**C#**

```
     string cmdArg = "C:\\Scripts\\GroupChangeGroup.ps1 1";
                    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
                    runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
                        runspace.Open();
                    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

 Command newcom = new Command("Add-PSSnapin");
                      newcom.Parameters.Add("Name", "microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.e2010");
                      pipeline.Commands.Add(newcom);

                  Command newcom2 = new Command("Add-PSSnapin");
                  newcom2.Parameters.Add("Name", "Microsoft.SharePOint.POwershell");
                  pipeline.Commands.Add(newcom2);

                    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg);
                    pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
                    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
                    var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();
                    runspace.Close();
```

**Powershell**

```
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://pc/websites/Test4/")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists["GroupsList - ListInstance1"]
$listitem = $list.Items.GetItemByID(3)
```

If I execute the application from PS there is no problem. (same user context)

The User is Member of `WSS_ADMIN_WPG`

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not work with .Net 4.0. PowerShell runs with .Net 3.5, that's why it works with PS.

You should switch back to .Net 3.5 SP1.

Also, be sure to set up your project to not run with X86 compilation settings.

Set it to AnyCPU or x64.

Comment: I changed the Framework to 3.5 and set Target CPU to x64 without success. I do not think that it is framework that makes the trouble, because the sharepoint actions are in a powershellscript? ...

Comment: try to add in you script `$farm = Get-Farm` and check if it's loaded correctly.

Comment: I thik you mean    $farm = Get-SPFarm?    If I execute this just in a ps-script it works. If I start the script from c# I get following failure: The term 'Get-SPFarm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: In the script, did you include `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePOint.POwershell` ? if no, you should do. It's not mandatory regarding the content of your script, but it may help to diagnose issues.

Comment: I've edited my questions code on your comment, but I still get the same error!

Comment: Ok, but if you add this snapin, what is the result of Get-SPFarm ?

Comment: Still: The term 'Get-SPFarm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

Comment: It is a matter of 64 bit target.